# How do I put 'end of text' (ETX, ASCII 3) in a string?

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I need to send a string over TPC/IP, and receiving end will listen for a string and read to a terminator which is ASCII 3. How can I put this in plain text into a textboks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Dimitrov said, do something like

```
textarea.Text += (Char) 3;
```

or

```
String text = textarea.Text + (Char) 3;
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't put this into the textbox, it's a binary character. You will add this to the value of the textbox before sending to the wire:

```
var ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
byte[] dataToSend = ascii
    .GetBytes("Some data from textbox")
    .Concat(ascii.GetBytes(new[] { (char)3 }))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [hexadecimal string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
string text = textbox.Text + "\x3";
```